# How does Domino deal with a dashed class name

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm attempting to create and use domino to abstract a login page

```
describe :index, :type => :request do
before do
  visit '/'
  blah_email_login('user1')
end
...

def blah_email_login(user)
  Dom::Email_Link.find_by_name 'Mail'.click
  ....
end

module Dom
  class Email_Link < Domino
  selector 'a'
  attribute :tab-label
end
```

here is the html

```
<a class="tab-label fz-xs accent " href="https://mail.blah.com/..." id="blah"><span class="tab-icon img-sprite"></span><em class="strong tab-link-txt y-link-1 " title="Mail">Mail</em></a>
```

The process cannot take a dash as indicated my the error I get pre run

```
C:\blah.rb:93:in `<class:Email_Link>': undefined local variable or method `label' for Dom::Email_Link:Class (NameError)
```

When I attempted to alter attribute to

```
 attribute :'tab-label'
```

I got ...

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/domino-0.5.0/lib/domino.rb:114:in `class_eval': (eval):2: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
    def tab-label
            ^
```

When I included escape characters

```
attribute :'tab\-label'
```

I got ...

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/domino-0.5.0/lib/domino.rb:114:in `class_eval': (eval):2: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
    def tab\-label
            ^
(eval):4: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ']'
      if value && self.class.callbacks[:tab\-label].is_a?(Proc)
```

The site I'm working with has many dashed class names, any ideas on how to work with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
module Dom
  class Email_Link < Domino
  selector 'a'
  attribute :'tab-label'
end
```

---

**Update**

Domino's default behavior is to replace `_` in attribute names to `-` in class names ([see here](https://github.com/ngauthier/domino/blob/master/lib/domino.rb#L112)).

Therefore your attribute name should use underscore:

```
module Dom
  class Email_Link < Domino
  selector 'a'
  attribute :tab_label
end
```